# Unable to publish changes from my branch - can only push changes to another branch, why?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

[image]

I have just created a new branch 'ie-eab-TD-IECC-25235-Junit'. I am trying to push my changes to the git repository on the same branch, however, this doesn't seem to be an option. --> See above picture which does not have the same branch name as an option for publishing commits to.

I can only push it to other branches, not the one I am on. Why is this happening and how do I push to the branch I am actually on?

My thoughts are that it is something to do with the upstream branch setup. But I am confused as I have followed the instructions for creating a new branch and then when I pull, thats when I have to set the upstream branch. And it might be this which is preventing me from pushing to itself (although I am not quite sure at the moment).

Comment: I suspect your hunch is correct. Running this from the command line: `git branch -vv` will show the upstream branches for all of your local branches. Likely either your branch doesn't have an upstream yet, or it's already pointing to a branch of a different name.

Comment: git branch -vv

* ie-eab-TD-IECC-25235-Junit 82590549b [origin/ie-eab-IECC-25521-TD: ahead 1] IECC-25235

Yes it seems it is pointing to another branch, how do I set it so that it points to the remote of the current branch instead?

Comment: You can unset it first: `git branch --unset-upstream`. I'm guessing your UI will then show you the option to create the remote branch with the same name (which may not even exist yet).

Comment: Weird. So for some reason when I unset the upstream branch, it has no set the remote branch as the same name as the local. Not sure why it didn't do this originally and instead forced me to set an upstream branch (without the same-name-remote as an option). But thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I believe we have enough info to answer now- I just added an answer explaining why that happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because your branch is currently tracking a remote branch with a different name. You can see all of your local branches and their remote tracking branches with this command:

`git branch -vv`

To fix it, simply unset your currently checkout out branch with this command:

`git branch --unset-upstream`

Now most Git UI's will offer you the opportunity to push your branch out to a remote branch with the same name, and typically by default will also set it to track for you.

**Why did this happen?**

Either you set it to the wrong branch at creation, or perhaps when you pulled (as you mentioned).

When you created the branch from a different branch name, you may have elected to "track" the remote branch too. Many UIs have an option which is selectable for whether to "track" the branch, and if it is a different name, most of the time you want to deselect that option, to prevent the exact issue you had. If you are creating your branch from the command line, you can use the `--no-track` argument, for example:

`git switch -c new-branch origin/existing-branch --no-track`

or the equivalent old(er) way:

`git checkout -b new-branch origin/existing-branch --no-track`

If you set it when (or right before) you pulled, then you can just push first and set it then, or next time add an argument containing the branch to pull from, e.g. `git pull origin some-branch-name` instead of using just `git pull`, which without arguments, requires you to have an upstream set to *something*.

Comment: Note that this kind of "tracking" is related to "remote-tracking [branch] names" like `origin/branch`, but unrelated to tracked vs untracked files. Git terminology for the ... um, something. Not "win". :-)

Comment: @torek Hehe. Right on. I'm sure someone has a list of ambiguous Git terms. "track", "checkout", and "commit" as both a verb and noun immediately come to mind. GitHub muddying the waters with "upstream" doesn't help either.